# GetThumbnailAsync is slow for some images

Tags: silverlight, windows-runtime, windows-store-apps, windows-phone-8.1

I have **Windows Phone 8.1 Silverlight** app which use `GetThumbnailAsync` method to show preview of images in Camera Roll. Almost all the time it works as expected and provide thumbnail within around 50-200 milliseconds. But for some of the images in my test device (Lumia 820), it takes around 10 seconds to return the thumbnail. However, when I copy same images to another test device (Lumia 1020), it works as expected. In Lumia 1020, still I didn't see this strange behaviour for any other image. Moreover, I didn't find any relation between this problem and size of the image. I really appreciate it if anyone can share any thought or experience on this issue.

**Edit**: Here is how I make the `GetThumbnailAsync` call in my app

```
var thumbnail = await selectedFile.GetThumbnailAsync(Windows.Storage.FileProperties.ThumbnailMode.SingleItem, 400)
```

Comment: Can you add details about the call the GetThumbanailAsync that you are making? There are a few subtleties on how the OS caches different sizes/aspect ratios on different resolution devices

Comment: Is there any relation as to the type of the image if its PNG?

Comment: No, all images are .jpg

Comment: Try deleting and re-adding the photo that is taking too long over the MTP connection. It is possible the system missed generating a cached thumbnail for the one picture. Readding it should kick it to make a new one